# makefile for boost crossplatform

Tags: c++, boost, makefile

I have created a makefile for a library I am compiling.

I have already got the makefile working on windows and linux , but there is a different makefile for each OS.
How could I allow this to work on both OS without hardcoding the path to the boost library and boost headers below:

Do I need to add the boost folder to the path variable?  do I need to add the library directory to some OS variable?

makefile windows:

```
# source files.
SRC = protoService.cpp protocolBaseServer.cpp client.cpp

OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

OUT = ../libutils.a

# include directories
INCLUDES = -I. -I../include/  -IC:\boost_1_59_0\

# C++ compiler flags (-g -O2 -Wall)
CCFLAGS = -g -MD -MP -std=c++0x -Wall -c

# compiler
CCC = g++

# library paths
LIBS = -LC:\boost_1_59_0\libs -lboost_serialization

# compile flags
LDFLAGS = -g

.SUFFIXES: .cpp

default: $(OUT)

.cpp.o:
    $(CCC) $(INCLUDES) $(CCFLAGS)  $< -o $@

$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    ar rcs $(OUT) $(OBJ)

#depend: dep

#dep:
#   makedepend -- $(CFLAGS) -- $(INCLUDES) $(SRC)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(OUT) Makefile.bak

-include $(DEPS:%.o=%.d)
```

makefile linux:

```
# source files.
SRC = protoService.cpp protocolBaseServer.cpp client.cpp

OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

OUT = ../libutils.a

# include directories
INCLUDES = -I. -I../include/ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/share/boost_1_58_0/

# C++ compiler flags (-g -O2 -Wall)
CCFLAGS = -g -MD -MP -std=c++0x -Wall -c

# compiler
CCC = g++

# library paths
LIBS = -L/usr/share/boost_1_58_0/lib/ -lboost_serialization

# compile flags
LDFLAGS = -g

.SUFFIXES: .cpp

default: $(OUT)

.cpp.o:
    $(CCC) $(INCLUDES) $(CCFLAGS)  $< -o $@

$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    ar rcs $(OUT) $(OBJ)

#depend: dep

#dep:
#   makedepend -- $(CFLAGS) -- $(INCLUDES) $(SRC)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(OUT) Makefile.bak

-include $(DEPS:%.o=%.d)
```

Comment: i found some info on CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH and LIBRARY_PATH.  Is that the solution I am looking for?  Then I could set the  boost library path and include folder on each machine I am compiling and the makefile would not need those paths?

Comment: confirmed.  Set CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH and LIBRARY_PATH as system variables and make searches these when including and linking

Answer (score 0):

Make passes environment variables to the makefile processor, so you can create make variables based on them.

```
INC_PATHS := ../include/ .
LIBS      += boost_serialization
ifeq ($(OS),"Windows_NT")
   INC_PATHS += ../include/ C:/boost_1_59_0/libs 
   LIBS      += boost_serialization
else
   INC_PATHS += /usr/local/include /usr/share/boost_1_58_0/lib/
endif
```

And then

```
INCLUDES = $(prepend -I,$(INC_PATHS))
```

or something like that.    I'm not in front of make to ensure the syntax is exactly correct, but it should get you moving in the right direction.